# Can someone explain what all the codes mean? PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
    i = 10
while i > 0:
        print i*'*' + 2*(10-i)*' ' + i*'*'
        i -= 1
for x in range(2,11):
        print x* '*' + 2*(10-x)*' '+ x*'*'
        x += 1
```

Can someone tell me what each line does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll keep it very simple, because this is very basic stuff.

`i = 10`

Variable `i` is initialised as 10.

```
while i > 0:
    print i*'*' + 2*(10-i)*' ' + i*'*'
    i -= 1
```

While variable `i` is bigger than 0, it prints the string `*` `i` times, an empty space `2 * (10 - i)` times and then the string `*` `i` times again. Every loop it subtracts 1 off of `i`, so `i` starts out as 10 and goes all the way down to 1. This results in the following triangle / pyramid:

```
********************
*********  *********
********    ********
*******      *******
******        ******
*****          *****
****            ****
***              ***
**                **
*                  *
```

```
for x in range(2,11):
    print x* '*' + 2*(10-x)*' '+ x*'*'
    x += 1
```

Here the variable `x` starts off as 2 and increments all the way to 10, which results in an upside down version of the above triangle (not exactly, but it would if you used `range(1, 11)` instead). Also `x += 1` is redundant here, as the `range` function will already increment `x` in steps of 1 (because the *step* argument is omitted). You can see this for yourself by running the following code:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print x
```